# Is there an incsearch for the replace command?

Tags: search, neovim, highlight

I really enjoy Vim's `incsearch` functionality. Is there a way to have it, or something similar to it, working while I do a replacement?

For example, if in normal mode I type:

```
:%s/potato/
```

Can I get all the `potato`s highlighted on my file, just like they are highlighted by `incsearch` when I write

```
/potato
```

?

This would already help me a lot when using regular expressions. A very very nice-to-have would be that when I write this:

```
:%s/potato/banana/
```

It would replace the `potato`s with `banana`s, and highlight them - maybe the replacements should be in a different color. It sould not "commit" the change until I pressed enter though).

I'm using neovim at the moment, in case it helps.

Comment: Do you mean `incsearch`? `hlsearch` should work ootb, if I type `:%s/potato/\0/` to replace `potato` with itself, then I see all matches highlighted.

Comment: Inded, I meant incsearch. Replacing in my question, thanks.

Comment: It's probably not kosher but `:/pattern<CR>` works fine then add the %s and the replace string. Thene again so does refine the search and use CTR-R/ to paste to the search part of `:%s/`

Comment: Appending to @jjaderberg: ``:%s/potato/carrot/c`` will let you jump ("confirm") through your replacements (add ``g`` to replace all instances on the same line) and with ``hlsearch`` you'll see them in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found [this NeoVim issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4794), which in turn was closed by [this PR](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/5561), which brought me to the `inccommand` setting. Adding this to my config file:

```
set inccommand=nosplit
```

makes NeoVim behave almost exactly as I requested in my question. I did not find something equivalent for regular Vim, but I didn't look for it very energetically.

Comment: In your situtaion, for `incsearch` in subtitutions (being a lazy Vimmer and slow to adopt neo things) I would probably search for potato (`/potato`) enjoying ordinary incremental search highlighighting, and then substitute with an empty search: `%s//banana`. But I don't know how it compares to `set inccommand=nosplit` in other respects.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the "empty search trick". I will try to remember it when I'm vim on my servers

Comment: @jjaderberg by the way I liked the `inccommand` setting so much that I made an asciinema showing it at work, in case it motivates you to give neovim a try: https://asciinema.org/a/3lzlyzn23c52wwp9mk644ft20

Comment: @jjaderberg I think that's worthy of being an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the asciinema is dead now.